# Can't compile java file using CLI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests, command-line-interface

I make some automated tests and faced with an issue that I can't compile the java.file
My source folder is the project's folder "Test".
In this folder i have 2 jar files:

**hamcrest-core-1.3.jar**

and

**junit-4.13.jar**

I run this command:

```
                javac -cp junit-4.13.jar;. src\r.java
```

And I got the next message:

```
src\r.java:1: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
                               ^
 src\r.java:1: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
 ^
 src\r.java:2: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue;
                               ^
 src\r.java:2: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue;
 ^
 src\r.java:4: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
                        ^
 src\r.java:5: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
                        ^
 src\r.java:6: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
                        ^
 src\r.java:7: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
                        ^
 src\r.java:8: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
                        ^
 src\r.java:9: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
                        ^
 src\r.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
 @BeforeAll
 ^
 symbol:   class BeforeAll
 location: class r
 src\r.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
 @BeforeEach
 ^
 symbol:   class BeforeEach
 location: class r
 src\r.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
 @Test
 ^
 symbol:   class Test
 location: class r
 src\r.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
 @Test
 ^
 symbol:   class Test
 location: class r
 src\r.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
 @Test
 ^
 symbol:   class Test
 location: class r
 src\r.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
 @Disabled("for demonstration purposes")
 ^
 symbol:   class Disabled
 location: class r
 src\r.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
 @Test
 ^
 symbol:   class Test
 location: class r
 src\r.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
 @AfterEach
 ^
 symbol:   class AfterEach
 location: class r
 src\r.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
 @AfterAll
 ^
 symbol:   class AfterAll
 location: class r
 src\r.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    fail("a failing test");
    ^
 symbol:   method fail(String)
 location: class r
 src\r.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    assumeTrue("abc".contains("Z"));
    ^
 symbol:   method assumeTrue(boolean)
 location: class r
 src\r.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    fail("test should have been aborted");
    ^
 symbol:   method fail(String)
 location: class r
 22 errors
```

My code is the template from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

```
     import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
     import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue;

     import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

 class r {

@BeforeAll
static void initAll() {
}

@BeforeEach
void init() {
}

@Test
void succeedingTest() {
}

@Test
void failingTest() {
    fail("a failing test");
}

@Test
@Disabled("for demonstration purposes")
void skippedTest() {
    // not executed
}

@Test
void abortedTest() {
    assumeTrue("abc".contains("Z"));
    fail("test should have been aborted");
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
}

@AfterAll
static void tearDownAll() {
}

 }
```

What I do wrong?
Please, help!

Comment: Thanks. I created a JUnit test with version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.junit.juniper` packages indicates that your code uses JUnit 5.

But you've only got JUnit 4 on your classpath.

Either follow the [JUnit 4 user guide](https://junit.org/junit4/) or change your classpath to include JUnit 5.